# pcap into qthread

Tags: libpcap, qthread

I'm writing an application under `Linux`, using Qt library.

So, there are two `QThreads`. In one of the threads `pcap_next()` function is calling in `while` cycle. All threads often using public members of each other during its working.

Without using `pcap` library (for example read packet from hard disk) everything is right, but when I try to put pcap's functions into separate `thread`, I have SEGFAULT error.

I can't understand how `pcap` works. Its looks like `pcap` freezes the whole process, and because of this threads can't get access to public members of each other.

The main `run()` function of pcap's thread looks like:

```
while()
{
   Data = pcap_next(handle, &header);
   if (Data...)
   {
        //processing functions
   }
}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

"Freezing the whole process" would keep the other threads from even *running*; it wouldn't cause the process to crash.

If your program makes simultaneous calls on a single `pcap_t` in more than one thread, other than some safe calls such as `pcap_breakloop()` (which will not interrupt a thread that's blocked - you'd need to deliver a signal in UN*X to do that), there is no guarantee that it will work.

If you never make simultaneous pcap calls on the same `pcap_t` in different threads, it should work.

I.e., you could open the device/savefile in one thread, getting a `pcap_t`, and, once that's done, have the same thread or another thread read packets from the `pcap_t`.  You could not, however, have *more than one* thread read packets from the `pcap_t`.

However, there could be something wrong with the way you're using pcap, in a fashion that would crash even in a single-threaded program.  We'd have to see all your pcap calls to see whether that's the case.

Comment: Then, as I said, we'd have to see all your pcap calls to see whether you're using pcap correctly.